# If $M$ is compact, $x(M)$ have no self-intersection?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $x:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an immersion and $M$ be a connected orientable smooth surface with possibly non-empty boundary, the title statement is right?

I have already known,
If $M$ is compact, injective immersion is embedding.
(This theorem is similar to the above, but it is already assumed injective condition.)

and I have thought that statement almost is correct..because I think these assumtions are sharp. in case, non-orientable, klein Bottle is counter example.

Can you comment to me or let me to know ref.?

Comment: What is the definition that $x(M)$ has no intersection?

Comment: $x(M)$ are image in ${R}^3$, and it has self-intersections, for example klein bottle

Comment: You need to give a precise definition, or nothing can be proved.

Answer (score 3):

First, $x$ is a terrible name for a function that is likely to need to use $x$ as a coordinate.

Let $M$ be the closed unit disk, which we may imagine living in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$.  $M$ is connected, orientable, smooth, and compact with one connected, orientable, smooth, and compact  boundary component.

Let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be $f(x,y) = (x^2,y,x^3-x/2)$.  You give no conditions on how wild $f$ is allowed to be, but you do mention smoothness.  This $f$ is smooth.  The image of $f$ has an intersection (of codimension $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$).
[image: Mathematica graphics]

There's really no way compactness can ensure embedding.  The smallest example is the map from $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ to $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ which *is* an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the extension of the map to the compact (closure) $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ is no longer an embedding (since the map is now no longer injective).

Comment: thank you. Eric Towers